# how to reduce learning rate on train correctly

Tags: python, keras, neural-network

I am training a neural network and I want to reduce the learning rate while training.
I am currently using `ReduceLROnPlateau` function provided by keras. But then it reaches the patience factor, it simply stops and don't continue training.

I want to reduce the learning rate and keep the net training.

Here is my code.

```
optimizer=k.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=1e-5)
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
            optimizer=optimizer,
            metrics=['acc'])


learningRate=callbacks.callbacks.ReduceLROnPlateau(monitor='val_acc', verbose=1, mode='max',factor=0.2, min_lr=1e-8,patience=7)

model.fit_generator(generator=training_generator,
                        validation_data=validation_generator,
                        steps_per_epoch=1000,
                        epochs=30,
                        validation_steps=1000,
                        callbacks=[learningRate]
                         )
```

Answer (score 1):

You're using `EarlyStopping` which is stopping your training.

> I want to reduce the learning rate and keep the net training but don't know how to do it.

If you want this then remove `EarlyStopping`.

Comment: Or change the LR scheduler.

Comment: I tried but its almost the same, just when it reach patience it says that the learning rate have been reduced but the training still stop. Ill now edit the main question.

Comment: Could be a Keras bug, there is a mistake in the docs: https://keras.io/callbacks/#reducelronplateau.
"patience: number of epochs that produced the monitored quantity with no improvement after which training will be stopped." When it should be "after which learning rate will decrease".